# Edge clipping algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement [this method](https://graphics.ethz.ch/Downloads/Publications/Papers/2001/p_Hub01b.pdf) of edge detection on 3D meshes and I got fairly impressive results. But its far from good.
The proposed thinning algorithm is returning funky branched edges, that aren't really useful. I think it could be my fault on reproducing the algorithm in python.

https://s1.postimg.org/87w1ul2zxb/Screen_Shot_20171009161230.png

So I guess there are three ways to solve this right now.
- Find a way to clip those short branches
- Find my error on the algorithm.
- Or try to make another thinning algorithm.

And I wasn't capable of doing any of these things.

Comment: What's your question? :)

Comment: I need to find an algotithm that is capable of selecting and deleting those short branches on the hilighted edges.